# How to write a function to print out a item in dictionary?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am trying to define and call a function but I am stuck on what to put all I know currently is that I definitely need a for loop .

I want my output to be 867-5309

from an input of

Input 1: Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309

Input 2: Frank

Though obviously I need it to work for any input that is placed into the name input

```
def get_phone_number(my_dict, contact_name):
    phone_number = ''
        
    
    
    return phone_number
    
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_pairs = input()
    my_list = word_pairs.split()
    
    name = input()
    
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
        my_dict[my_list[i]] = my_list[i + 1]

    print(get_phone_number(dict, name))
```

I already know my dictionary works fine my only problem is with formatting a function that will give me the output I want, I am struggling with functions and just need a little help to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function for this. And least of all a loop. You can just call the entry of `my_dict` using the key:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_pairs = input("Enter Words: ")
    my_list = word_pairs.split()
    
    name = input("Enter Name: ")
    
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
        my_dict[my_list[i]] = my_list[i + 1]

    print(my_dict[name])
```